# I can't adjust width of table cell

Tags: html, css

I have a strange problem. I want to have fixed width of table cell with break-word property when the word inside the cell is too long. Breaking work is working but the width of cell is still bigger than I specified. Here is the table with stylesheet:

```html
<table style="table-layout: fixed">
  <thead>
    <th style="width: 100px;"><span>EMAIL</span>
    </th>
    <th style="width: 100px;"><span>FULL NAME</span>
    </th>
    <th style="width: 100px;"><span>ORGANIZATION NAME</span>
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td style="width: 100px;">
      <div style="max-width: 100px; word-wrap: break-word; ">
        abc
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 100px;">
      <div style="max-width: 100px; word-wrap: break-word; ">
        efg
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 100px;">
      <div style="max-width: 100px; word-wrap: break-word; ">
        lalalalallalalalalallalalalalalallalalalalallalalalalalalalallalalalla
      </div>
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am getting the result:

[image]

and I would like to the email column to have width = 100px.

Thanks for any help. I have no idea how to change it.

Comment: The image does not correspond to the content of the code snippet. The question does not specify on which browser(s) the issue was observed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `overflow: hidden`, `text-overflow: ellipsis;`  and `max-width: 100px` to `th`with long text:

```html
<table style="table-layout: fixed">
    <thead>
        <th style="width: 100px;"><span>EMAIL</span>

        </th>
        <th style="width: 100px;"><span>FULL NAME</span>

        </th>
        <th style="max-width: 100px;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span>ORGANIZATION NAME</span>

        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td style="width: 100px;">
            <div style="max-width: 100px; word-wrap: break-word; ">lalalalallalalalalallalalalalalallalalalalallalalalalalalalallalalallalalalalallalalalalallalalalalalallalalalalallalalalalalalalallalalalla</div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 100px;">
            <div style="max-width: 100px; word-wrap: break-word; ">efg</div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 100px;">
            <div style="max-width: 100px; word-wrap: break-word; ">lalalalallalalalalallalalalalalallalalalalallalalalalalalalallalalalla</div>
        </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It did not help. I think it is not the issue of th but the browser somehow remembers width of div before its content is broken and after that it can't be set to something diffrent.

Comment: can you post a fiddle to demonstrates the problem?